# Link to sheet with filter applied

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel table:

[image]

And I want to create a metric that will tell me the Count of Rows where Country=US:

[image]

The answer should be "2" of course. How would I make the number "2" link to the `Raw` tab with the Filter Country="US" applied? To get the number I can do: `=COUNTIF(Table2[Country],"US")`, but how would I link and have the filter applied?

Comment: It is not clear which filter you are talking about ...

Comment: @Ike clicking the Country context menu and changing the filter there:  https://gyazo.com/fc5aa2ac7b775a4644ae5a69a8b977c3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do this without diving into the VBA code, but here is a solution for the above:

1. You can use the table formula: `=COUNTIF(Table2[Country],"US")`.
2. In that cell right-click and add a hyperlink in "This Document" and enter in the location of the cell that was clicked, for example `B2`.
3. The following VBA code is what I used:

```
(general)
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Raw").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "US"
End Sub
```

```
(worksheet)
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Call Macro1
         End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

`=AGGREGATE(3,1,Table2[country])`

It will return the number of visible rows in the filtered table.

If you filter by CA it will return 1 ... that would not fit to the to text left of it

Comment: sure, I included the count correctly in the question, I'm more interested in clicking that count to hyperlink to the filtered table.

Comment: then you should update your question - this is not clear at all